# AS3: odd instance name behavior when removing

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

So i have narrowed down my problem to this:

i have two instances of a movieclip ("content1", "content2") added into two different other movieclips ("container1", "container2"). I want to remove them.

As soon as i remove one of them with this horrible command...

```
MovieClip(MovieClip(root).getChildByName("container1")).removeChild(MovieClip(MovieClip(root).getChildByName("container1")).getChildByName("content1"));
```

...the other instance of it changes its instance name to a generic one (like "instance25") and i can't access it anymore with getChildByName.

Can anyone explain this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never experienced that behaviour - regardless, what you can do is store reference to both before you remove them. This way, you won't need their original instance name to remove both:

```
var top:MovieClip = root as MovieClip;

var cotainer:MovieClip = top.container1;
var content1:MovieClip = container.getChildByName("content1");
var content2:MovieClip = container.getChildByName("content2");

container.removeChild(content1);
container.removeChild(content2);
```

Hopefully this answer gives you some hints for making your code much more readable as well.